# Why do my Rigid Bodies ignore their physical boundries and collapse into each other?

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation

I have a stack of casino chips, made from cylinders.
I want them to stay stacked until I push them over after 264 frames.
However, when I click play, the chips seem to collapse under their own weight?
Also, I noticed they fall into each other, almost like they have no top/bottom cap.

**Question:**

Can somebody take a look and tell me how to fix it, so they don't fall down on their own at the start?

**Rigid Body settings**

[image: Rigid Body settings]

**This is what happens**

[image: Issue]

[.blend file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aufy0vw2uZxPgaMIiT4_rIxkaOHiiA?e=tE1LQZ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the *Scene* panel, under *Rigid Body*, increase the *Substeps per Frame* up to 50 for example, it will improve the calculation of the simulation:

[image]

Comment: So simpel, but so effective. Thank you!!!